Transfer of the reactive stream to the reactive processing .flatMap() causes memory overflow
I have a problem. In my controller method, a reactive stream parameter comes into the parameter where a large file Mono, I need to transfer it to S3 without loading it into memory, just as a stream. But with reactive processing in the method .flatMap(. throws the error that "Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144" i.e. the stream is subtracted and exceeds the size. How do I transfer a stream without reading it into memory?
`public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> createImage(Mono<InputStreamResource> inputStreamResource) {
        return inputStreamResource
                .flatMap(resource -> {
                    try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
                        Upload upload = transferManager.upload(
                                "bucketName", "test", inputStream, new ObjectMetadata());

                        upload.waitForCompletion();
                        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok("test"));
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException(e));
                    }
                });
    }`

How is transferring a stream to S3 without unloading it into memory?
